# Show substitution leads to a separable differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation...

> $y' = f(\frac{y}{t})$

Show that the substitution $v = \frac{v}{t}$ leads to a separable differential equation in $v$

Here's what I did.

> $v = \frac{y}{t}$
>
> $\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dt} - \frac{1}{t^2}$

Sub into the orignal.

> $\frac{dv}{dt} = f(v) - \frac{1}{t^2}$
>
> $\frac{dv}{f(v)} =\frac{1}{t^2}dt$

This is where I get stuck. Is this the what the question is asking for, or am I forgetting to do something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if you substitute $v=\frac{y}{t} \Rightarrow y=vt$. Note that $v$ is assumed to be a function of $t$.
Using the product rule, we obtain the derivative $y'$:
$$y=v(t)\cdot t \Rightarrow y'=\frac{dv}{dt}\cdot t+v \tag{1}$$
Substituting into $y'=f\left(\frac{y}{t}\right)$:
$$\frac{dv}{dt}\cdot t+v=f(v)$$
Now, try to separate the variables. i.e, put only $v$ and $dv$ terms on one side of the equality and $t$ and $dt$ terms on the other side, then you are done.

Feel free to ask on the comments if you have any related doubts or questions.

Comment: is 

$\frac{t}{dt}= \frac{f(v) - v}{dv}$ 

okay? Are $dt$ and $dv$ allowed to be on the bottom of the fraction? Also, can $f(v)$ be expressed in another way? Like $v$ alone, or no?

Comment: You are one step away! Just take the reciprocal on both sides, then you are done. No, $f(v)$ should be left like this.

Comment: $\frac{dt}{t}= \frac{dv}{f(v) - v}$ ?

Comment: **Yes, that is correct.** Therefore, your differential equation is separable. By the way, to answer your question about $f(v)$: $f(v)$ should be left as it is. Otherwise, it loses its generality. For example if you say $f(v)$, it can mean **any function of $v$**. If you just say $v$, it means $v$ **only**.